# arraysort MWE, Package arraysort Error: Cannot sort by undefined comparator arraysortcompare str

Tags: errors, arrays, sorting

Hello can you help me produce a MWE for arraysort ?

I put in a minimal document the code from the documentation of Arraysort Package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{arraysort}

\begin{document}

\newarray{A}
\readarray{A}{78&4&85&1&28&6}
\sortArray{6}{A}
\A(1) \A(2) \A(3) \A(4) \A(5) \A(6)

\end{document}
```

It gives of :

```
  Package arraysort Error: Cannot sort by undefined comparator arraysortcomparestr.
```

Thank you

Comment: there are examples in the documentation, and on page 6 it says that you need to use a package option to load comparators. `\usepackage[comparestr,comparenum,randompart]{arraysort}`. (I would use expl3, which can do this fine too.)

Comment: And I think you should remove your rant. The fact is that you obviously didn't read the documentation. It took me only three minutes to find the info, and I had never seen the package before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know there are examples in the doc, I used one of them in my question, I'm just asking for one that works. (implied: on its own)

Comment: I am happy to hear that this documentation works for you, I am saying it should work for everybody by providing a MWE. If you can provide one I'll clear this post.

Comment: Then write the author a nice mail and tell him that the description is unclear to you. Ranting on the internet is at first useless and at second simply bad manner.

Answer (score 1):

First, the bubble sort using no packages.  Then the array read, using `listofitems`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
% THIS CODE CAN \bubblesort A NUMBERED LIST
%
\def\listterminator{9999}% SET TO *ANY* VALUE KNOWN NOT TO BE IN LIST (POSITIVE OR NEGATIVE)
\newcommand\bubblesort[1]{\def\sortedlist{}\sortlist#1,\listterminator,\relax}
\def\sortlist#1,#2,#3\relax{%
  \ifnum#2=\listterminator\relax%
    \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1}%
  \else
    \ifnum#1<#2\relax%
      \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1,}%
      \sortlist#2,#3\relax%
    \else%
      \let\tmp\sortedlist%
      \def\sortedlist{}%
      \expandafter\sortlist\tmp#2,#1,#3\relax%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
Bubble Sort Demonstration: 
\bubblesort{78,4,85,1,28,6}\sortedlist\par
\readlist*\A{\sortedlist}
Array spans \A[1] to \A[6]:
\foreachitem\z\in\A[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1 \else, \fi\z}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your initial list is in a `\def`, then you would get it started as

```
\def\mylist{78,4,85,1,28,6}
\expandafter\bubblesort\expandafter{\mylist}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work if the numbers are not integers

Comment: @LMT-PhD Yes, it is limited to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Ulrike Fischer for the help on the documentation.

I just needed to add

```
 \usepackage[comparestr,comparenum,randompart]{arraysort}
```

in the beginning

Reading the doc it seemed to me that it needed more, but no.